# How to allow non-admin users in a Windows domain to install a specific application?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory

I have a Windows 2008 domain with Vista workstations.

I don't want users to have admin rights on their machines, but I want to allow them to install a specific company application.

This application is signed.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest that group policy would be perfect for this - the software is installed at logon (usually invisibly) and the users need no additional rights at all.

[This link at Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816102) gives an overview.

Comment: Correct solution if you have a MSI built wich supports unattended installation (msiexec /qb). Note that software published via GPO gets installed before the user logs on.

Answer (score 1):

Create an AD group, such as "Corporate Application". Add the machines that you want to receive the app to this group.

Create a Startup Script which installs this app when the computer restarts, add the startup script to group policy.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used them but you might be able to do this with [Software restriction policies](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457006.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I've deployed non-MSI installers using the Symantec deployment tool included with the anti-virus corp edition.  When selecting a package to deploy just pointed it at the setup.exe file that I wanted to have installed, instead of the anti-virus client and ran though the same steps as if it was the symantec anti-virus client that was being installed.

Don't know if you have symantec corp but if you do, thats an option.